# Dynamic Templates in Django Views

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am wondering whether it is possible to insert template names dynamically into Django views from `urls.py`.

That is, suppose I have an app whose entire purpose is to serve as a container for various static landing pages. The plan is to create this app and have various entries in its `urls.py` correspond to paths to various landing pages. Each page would have a separate `.html` correspond to it.

The question is whether one could get away with writing only one (class-based or other) view for all of these templates or would there need to be a view for each page?

Django version 2.1-2.2

P.S. If there is an alternative, laconic way of accomplishing something similar, I am all ears.

Comment: in a class based view you can override get_template_names method

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a variable in the URL and a simple function based view

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import landing_page_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:template_name>/', landing_page_view, name='landing_page_view'), # Your urls will be <host>/template_name
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def landing_page_view(request, template_name):
    return render(request, f'{template_name}.html') # Render view with the template corresponding with the template_name in the url
```